# Creating a global floating button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to have floating button visible throughout the life cycle of the app on top of all pages? I know that with `Scaffold` I can have it but it only works for that page and i'll lose it once I push a new page on the navigator stack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use the `builder` of the `MaterialApp` to create a `Stack` with your Button on top:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: TestPage(),
      initialRoute: "/test",
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              child!,
              Positioned(
                    left: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: **your button here**,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: routes(context),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `OverlayEntry` is made for this purpose.

To insert it, you can do something like this:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text("Overlay Test"),
  onPressed: () {
    final entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(entry);
  },
)
```

If you want to remove it later, you can save the `entry` variable and then call `entry.remove()` when needed.

Full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  OverlayEntry? _entry;
  double _left = 50;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("OverlayEntry Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Add OverlayEntry"),
              onPressed: () {
                _entry = OverlayEntry(
                  builder: (context) {
                    print("build");
                    return Positioned(
                      left: _left,
                      top: 200,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
                Overlay.of(context)?.insert(_entry!);
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Move it"),
              onPressed: () {
                _left += 10;
                _entry?.markNeedsBuild();
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Remove it"),
              onPressed: () => _entry?.remove(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When I put it in `main.dart`, before pushing the first page, it shows nothing

Comment: @Maysam I added a full example code to the answer, you can try it out by deleting everything in `main.dart` and copy-paste the full example code there.

Comment: Thanks but it won't work for my use case

Comment: how can I remove the Overlay in an another page? shall I go back to the page which I added the button for remove it? Or how can I add a button inside this overlay to remove it, when required, without bothering go back to the previous page?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, very similar to @puelo's answer.

But making use of the floating action button.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    routes: routes,
    initialRoute: HomePage.routeName,
    builder: (context, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: child,
        floatingActionButton: MyButton(),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      );
    },
  );
}
```